# Fluent NHibernate - How to customize "left join" condition?

Tags: nhibernate, join, conditional-statements, fluent

Is there a way to add and customize some LEFT JOIN conditions?
I need it to be generated like the next native SQL (Oracle query):

```
LEFT JOIN TableB B ON SomeStoredProc(MainTable.ColumnA || MainTable.ColumnB) = B.TableB_Key
LEFT JOIN TableC C ON C.Some_TableC_Column = B.Some_TableB_Column
```

I need both JOINs to be in the same query.

So, I need some help with the three points:

- How to add Storec Procedure call;
- How to add "||" (concatenation) operator usage;
- How to add two LEFT JOINs to the same query?

Thank you very much!

Comment: AFAIK Nhibernate does not support sprocs in join column. Maybe you could map the one to many to tableb with a sql query in the collection mapping

Comment: I'm not sure, can you show some sample?

Answer (score 0):

some ideas to try

- `<bag property-ref="(SomeStoredProc( ColumnA || ColumnB))"`
- `<bag where="(SomeStoredProc( ColumnA || ColumnB))"`
- maybe tweak this `<many-to-many formula="any SQL expression"`